# Error when trying to install eralchemy in Jupyter from a Windows device

Tags: python, jupyter

Good day

When I run the command
pip install eralchemy
in a clear Jupyter notebook from a Windows device, I get the lengthy error message below. I have already installed Graphviz with Chocolate and Visual Studio with its BuildTools. Any help?

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command: 'C:\Users\stanj\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools,
> tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\stanj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pw34pfvb\pygraphviz\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\stanj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pw34pfvb\pygraphviz\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\stanj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-68acdv22'
> cwd: C:\Users\stanj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pw34pfvb\pygraphviz\
> Complete output (46 lines):   running bdist_wheel   running build
> running build_py   creating build Collecting eralchemy   Using cached
> ERAlchemy-1.2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB) Collecting pygraphviz
> Using cached pygraphviz-1.7.zip (118 kB) Requirement already
> satisfied: SQLAlchemy in c:\users\stanj\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
> (from eralchemy) (1.3.18) Building wheels for collected packages:
> pygraphviz   Building wheel for pygraphviz (setup.py): started
> Building wheel for pygraphviz (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
> Running setup.py clean for pygraphviz Failed to build pygraphviz
> Installing collected packages: pygraphviz, eralchemy
> Running setup.py install for pygraphviz: started
> Running setup.py install for pygraphviz: finished with status 'error'   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8   creating
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz   copying pygraphviz\agraph.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz   copying pygraphviz\graphviz.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz   copying pygraphviz\scraper.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz   copying pygraphviz\testing.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz   copying pygraphviz_*init*_.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz   creating
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_attribute_defaults.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_clear.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_close.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_drawing.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_edge_attributes.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_graph.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_html.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_layout.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_node_attributes.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_readwrite.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_scraper.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_string.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_subgraph.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests\test_unicode.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   copying
> pygraphviz\tests_*init*_.py ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests   running egg_info   writing
> pygraphviz.egg-info\PKG-INFO   writing dependency_links to
> pygraphviz.egg-info\dependency_links.txt   writing top-level names to
> pygraphviz.egg-info\top_level.txt   reading manifest file
> 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'   reading manifest template
> 'MANIFEST.in'   warning: no files found matching '*.png' under
> directory 'doc'   warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under
> directory 'doc'   warning: no files found matching '*.css' under
> directory 'doc'   warning: no previously-included files matching '*~'
> found anywhere in distribution   warning: no previously-included files
> matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution   warning: no
> previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in
> distribution   no previously-included directories found matching
> 'doc\build'   writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> copying pygraphviz\graphviz.i -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz
>
> copying pygraphviz\graphviz_wrap.c ->
> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz   running build_ext   building
> 'pygraphviz.*graphviz' extension   error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is
> required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
>
> ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'C:\Users\stanj\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\stanj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pw34pfvb\pygraphviz\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\stanj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pw34pfvb\pygraphviz\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\stanj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v7o_3mbj\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\stanj\anaconda3\Include\pygraphviz'
> cwd: C:\Users\stanj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pw34pfvb\pygraphviz
>
> Complete output (46 lines):
> running install
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz
> copying pygraphviz\agraph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz
> copying pygraphviz\graphviz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz
> copying pygraphviz\scraper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz
> copying pygraphviz\testing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz
> copying pygraphviz_*init**.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz
> creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_attribute_defaults.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_clear.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_close.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_drawing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_edge_attributes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_graph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_html.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_layout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_node_attributes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_readwrite.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_scraper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_string.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_subgraph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> copying pygraphviz\tests_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz\tests
> running egg_info
> writing pygraphviz.egg-info\PKG-INFO
> writing dependency_links to pygraphviz.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
> writing top-level names to pygraphviz.egg-info\top_level.txt
> reading manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
> warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'doc'
> warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'doc'
> warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'doc'
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
> warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribution
> no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\build'
> writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
> copying pygraphviz\graphviz.i -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz
> copying pygraphviz\graphviz_wrap.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygraphviz
> running build_ext
> building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
> ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\stanj\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c
> 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\Users\stanj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pw34pfvb\pygraphviz\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\stanj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pw34pfvb\pygraphviz\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\stanj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v7o_3mbj\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\stanj\anaconda3\Include\pygraphviz' Check the logs for full
> command output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo! It works with GoogleColab. Thank you all for your contributions.

Here are the steps I followed with your help:

1. I opened the notebook with Google Colab
2. I saved my database and csv files in the content folder in Google Colab
3. I ran the following command as suggested:

> pip install --upgrade --no-deps
> git+https://github.com/psychemedia/eralchemy.git

4. I imported render_er from eralchemy

> from eralchemy import render_er

5. I drew from the database with ...

> render_er("sqlite:///**relative_path_to_db**.db", 'erd_from_sqlite.png')

6. And tada! it shows an ER Diagram of my database in Google Colab.

Now the follow-up question: Now that we know how to make it work in GoogleColab, can anyone figure out how to get it to work in Jupyter?

Comment: StackOverflow is not of a forum thread discussions style so no one will look for your follow-up question in an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

`pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+https://github.com/psychemedia/eralchemy.git`

Comment: I tried running this command in Jupyter. !pip3 install --upgrade --no-deps git+https://github.com/psychemedia/eralchemy.git. Then I got the following error .  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/psychemedia/eralchemy.git 'C:\Users\stanj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-0gh2743h'
  ERROR: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/psychemedia/eralchemy.git 'C:\Users\stanj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-0gh2743h'
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?.

Comment: I then Installed Git onto my Windows device, but still it gives the same error message. Any help?

Comment: @JacquesStander Try the command while using https://colab.research.google.com, It works just like Jupyter Notebooks in Anaconda.